# http.post request not receiving any data

Tags: ruby

I have a program that sends an HTTP request and receive the answer.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(server, port)
resp, data = http.post(path, url, headers)
```

After this I see resp with a value of `#<Net::HTTPOK:0x00005643dd572980>` and data empty, so I receive a
`no implicit conversion of nil into String` error afterwards when I use it.

I have never used Ruby so I'm a bit confused about what can be failing or how I can debug this. I capture network traffic and both the request and response are sent correctly, and the response contains the expected data.

Is there anything that can make `data` be empty? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation, the `Net::HTTP` `post` method returns an `HTTPResponse` object. Since there is only one object returned, only `resp` will be given a value.

You mentioned that "the response contains the expected data." I am wondering if you simply need to employ the `body` method. Does `resp.body` give you the data you are looking for?

See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post

Comment: You nailed it!  The original code must be wrong or made for another version, who knows